# Remove duplicate rows from two different lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy, tuples

I am trying to find unique elements in a list which are not present in another list and I have read some posts here but yet I dont get the wanted results. Maybe its because I have mixed strings and int in list?

```
import requests
import numpy as np


list1 = [['dog', 123, -10],['cat', 44, -5],['rabbit', 99, 2]]
list2 = [['dog', 123, -10],['parrot', 44, -5],['rabbit', 99, 2]]

#What we should be left with is ['parrot', 44, -5]

mixem = list1+list2

data = np.array(mixem)

new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data]
uniques = np.unique(new_array)
```

What am I doing wrong? What I want to be left is `['parrot', 44, -5]` which is the only unique row/set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you don't really require numpy to achieve what you are trying to do.

You can get the result that you require by simply using a for loop:

```
list1 = [['dog', 123, -10],['cat', 44, -5],['rabbit', 99, 2]]
list2 = [['dog', 123, -10],['parrot', 44, -5],['rabbit', 99, 2]]

uniques=[]
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
  if i!=j:
      uniques.append(j)

print(uniques)
```

To answer your question as to why np.unique() doesn't get you a unique tuple is that you are mistaken about how it is actually working in your case.

Take note that when you execute: data = np.array(mixem), it actually creates a numpy matrix, and so when you do np.unique(), it produces all the unique elements in the numpy matrix.

```
>>> data
>>> array([['dog', '123', '-10'],
       ['cat', '44', '-5'],
       ['rabbit', '99', '2'],
       ['dog', '123', '-10'],
       ['parrot', '44', '-5'],
       ['rabbit', '99', '2']], dtype='<U6')
```

In your code, the new_array list contains the following elements:

```
>> new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data]
>> new_array
>> [('dog', '123', '-10'), ('cat', '44', '-5'), ('rabbit', '99', '2'), ('dog', '123', '-10'), ('parrot', '44', '-5'), ('rabbit', '99', '2')]
```

and hence, uniques[] contains:

```
>>> uniques = np.unique(new_array)
>>> uniques
array(['-10', '-5', '123', '2', '44', '99', 'cat', 'dog', 'parrot',
       'rabbit'], dtype='<U6')
```

You actually are having a list of lists initially and then you are converting it into a numpy array(by doing,  data = np.array(mixem) ) and then again you are converting it into a list of tuples(by doing,  new_array = [tuple(row) for row in data] ) and finally you are again converting it back into a numpy array(by doing, uniques = np.unique(new_array) ) which doesn't make sense, as a lot of code is actually redundant.

Well, even if np.uniques would somehow work to provide you the unique tuples, then it would produce 4 unique tuples, ie:
[('dog', '123', '-10'), ('cat', '44', '-5'), ('rabbit', '99', '2'), ('parrot', '44', '-5')]

To produce this result, you need to use axis=0 as the parameter as shown below:

```
>>> uniques = np.unique(new_array, axis=0)
>>> uniques
array([['cat', '44', '-5'],
       ['dog', '123', '-10'],
       ['parrot', '44', '-5'],
       ['rabbit', '99', '2']], dtype='<U6')
```

What you are trying to do is:

> 1)Compare list1 and list2.
>
> 2)Display elements of list 2 which are not present in list1.

What you are actually doing:

> 1)Concatinating list1 and list2.
>
> 2)Creating numpy matrix consisting of the list1 and list2.
>
> 3)Finding unique elements in the matrix.

Comment: With deepest gratitude, not only for providing the answer how to solve the problem but also the explanations.

Comment: It's my pleasure to help you out!! :)

Comment: This only works if the lists are arranged in the same order. Otherwise it does not

Comment: @Onyambu to avoid such situation just run one loop upon the other i.e J over I and not simultaneously as shown in the answere.

Comment: you do not need  two loops. you need `[i for i in list2 if i not in list1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,j in zip(list1,list2):
  if i!=j:
    print(i)
    print(j)

Output:-
['cat', 44, -5]
['parrot', 44, -5]
```

Using this you will get both now if u want only '['parrot,44,-5]' just keep 'j' inside the loop :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets to remove duplicates from list. Please note this is one of the many ways to do it, maybe with pandas, numpy etc.

```
#given list
list1 = [['dog', 123, -10],['cat', 44, -5],['rabbit', 99, 2]]
list2 = [['dog', 123, -10],['parrot', 44, -5],['rabbit', 99, 2]]

#convert the list to set
set1 = set((tuple(row) for row in list1))
set2 = set((tuple(row) for row in list2))

#use symmetric difference to find the unique elements
s = set1.symmetric_difference(set2) #this will return a set

#to convert back to list
list3 = [list(ele) for ele in s]
```

Since the lists are mutable, first you need to convert them to tuple, otherwise converting them directly to list using `set(list1)` will throw an error.